# C++ constexpr functions with dynamic memory allocations

Tags: c++, c++20

As an illustrative example, given a constexpr string literal, I want to transform that into another constexpr data structure. Since this transformation is purely side-effect free, I'd wish for a way to do that at compile time (without a preprocessor but with standard C++ language features).

Now, I am certain that at one point I read about a potential future feature addition to C++2a (or later) that *would* allow dynamic memory allocation within a constexpr function, that would definitely be the solution to my problem. - but I cannot find the article, that was telling me that, anymore.

Is there a way to perform dynamic memory allocations within a constexpr context in C++ already, or does anyone know which paper is proposing that?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0784r1.html) can help?

Comment: Dynamic allocation could be part of a constexpr function at run time that would be excluded for true constexpr at compile time since constexpr functions can be "called" at both runtime and compile time. But clearly one can't do compile time dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @doug: "*clearly one can't do compile time dynamic memory allocation*" Today. What happens tomorrow is to be determined, and the C++ committee seems to want it to happen.

Comment: @NicolBolas  I suppose it's a matter of the definition of dynamic. One can potentially use `new` to process `constexpr` algos to precalculate a constant data segment and such a device could be quite useful for embedded systems. I really don't like calling that "dynamic" and am not sure what advantage it would have given that static, `constexpr`  data can already be precalculated quite well and without the indirection associated with dynamic allocation. Interesting to see how it develops.

Comment: Many thanks @codekaizer. The authors of this paper are having the same motivations as I do.

doug, nicol-bolas: my motivation lies behind transforming a constexpr string containing a list of regexp rules into an NFA, that into a DFA, that into a minimized DFA, that in the end leads to a 2 dimentional table of transition states and an accept mapping. That process is completely side-effect free and would (with codekaizer's paper being realized) eliminate the need of an external pre-compiler that does the transformation.

Comment: @christianparpart That certainly would be an effective use of existing library functionality that would be complex to do within the confines of C++17 constexpr functions. The dynamic part is transient in the compile phase producing a relatively small static section for the executable. Reflecting, I wonder if this sort of thing would help get rid of the moc requirement in qt.  It has all sorts of possibilities if one could use the full set of libraries or and even external ones to create static, precrunched data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such feature is scheduled for **C++20**. However, the allocated memory must not leak into the runtime. This might be problematic if your constexpr data structure needs to hold the allocated memory. You can find more information about the feature and why non-transient allocations are problematic in [P0784](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0784r7.html).